# Get user location when app runs and re-center again after moving around using a button

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, core-location

I'm working on a project about MapKit using Swift 3. What the code below does is once I load the app the map will load in default. Then when the user presses the button it takes you to the user's location.

The way I want to fix this is I want it to load the user's location as soon as the app runs, and then when the user decides to move around the screen, she/he could hit the button and then recenter the user location again. Like how it works on Maps.

[image: when app loads capture image]

[image: when button is hit]

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    // connecting the map from the mainBoard and refering to it as "myMap".....
    @IBOutlet weak var myMap: MKMapView!

    @IBAction func refLocation(_ sender: Any) {
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    let manager = CLLocationManager()

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location  = locations.last {
            let span: MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.0075,0.0075)
            let myLocation :CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
            let region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
            myMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        }

        self.myMap.showsUserLocation = true

        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what you're asking.

If you want to get a single location update you can use the function `func requestLocation()`.

You could create a location manager (and set yourself as its delegate) in your view controller's viewDidLoad and call `requestLocation()` once.

Then call `requestLocation()` again in your button action.

Make your didUpdateLocations method always recenter the map. That way you'll receive one and only one update from clicking your button, and the map will recenter as soon as the update is received.

Comment: i need the app to load the map with the user location when the app runs. However, i want to give the user the ability to move around the map when he needs. and once the user wants to re-center the map, the user will use the button to recenter the user location. i hope this is clear.

Comment: Will you display your map view controller on launch? If so, the steps I describe will do exactly what you want. (The app launches. It displays the view  controller that contains your map. The view controller's `viewDidLoad()` method starts the location manager and requests a location. When the location is delivered, the map view controller centers the map on that location. Likewise the button action requests a location, and recenter the map on that location when the update arrives.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for **Swift 3**

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation


class ViewController2: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var currentLocation = CLLocation()
var currentLat: Double!
var currentLon: Double!
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myLocation()
}


func myLocation()
{
    if currentLocation.coordinate.latitude == 0.00 || currentLocation.coordinate.longitude == 0.0
    {
        print("no location")
    }
    else
    {
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()
        {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        }

        let locManager = CLLocationManager()
        locManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        if(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse ||
            CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedAlways)
        {
            currentLocation = locManager.location!
        }

        print("currentLongitude: \(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)")
        print("currentLatitude: \(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)")

        currentLon = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude
        currentLat = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude

        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.2, 0.2)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: currentLat, longitude: currentLon), span: span)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }

}

@IBAction func MyLocationBtnPressed(_ sender: Any)
 {
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.1, 0.1)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: currentLat, longitude: currentLon), span: span)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to call `startUpdatingLocation()` again because MapView always knows userLocation.

Replace

```
@IBAction func refLocation(_ sender: Any) {
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

with

```
@IBAction func refLocation(_ sender: Any) {
    let region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myMap.userLocation.coordinate, myMap.region.span)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
```